# Fonts Choices Can Not be seen at Night

Tags: macos, display, pages, night-shift

The font choice are on the right side of the screen on Pages. At night I have to click on a font choice for it to be visible. In the day they are easily readable. This just started happening on my Macbook 2016 .

I removed the Night Shift Display but the font choices did not become visible. I have not changed anything on my computer.

How can I have it visible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your Mac is running macOS Sierra or later and your Mac has Night Shift enabled (by default Night Shift will change the appearance of your screen at night).

To access Night Shift settings go to **Apple > System Preferences > Displays** and select the **Night Shift** tab (see screenshot below):

[image]

<sup>Depending on your version of macOS your Displays preference pane may look slightly different to the image above.</sup>

Now you have two options:

- Totally disable Night Shift by selecting "Off" from the Schedule drop-down menu
- Experiment with the Color Temperature slider (at night with Pages open) to see if you can get it so that your font choices are easier to read.

**NOTE:** You shouldn't have to reboot for the changes to take effect, but if they don't when you're expecting them to (e.g. you set a schedule from 7pm and nothing changes even though it's already after 7pm), you may need to reboot for the change to take effect.